# How to display users from two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables-members and addclique. Members table contains the details of all users while addclique table is 'friends' table with two columns-adder_id, which contains id of the user that sent a friend request and clique_id, contains the id of user that accepted the friend request.

Please am trying to select the friends of a particular user but am finding hard getting the details (photo, name, etc) of the friends from the members table because I don't know at which point to join members table to the addclique table.

```
$sql = "SELECT i.*, m.* FROM addclique i JOIN members m ON m.id = ******** WHERE adder_id = :id OR clique_id = :id";

$result= $db->query($sql, array('id' => $_SESSION['id']);
```

Comment: Are you wanting us to tell you which field in your addclique table to join on your m.id?

Comment: Please identify your Primary and Foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

The query below will select all members that a particular person has added plus all members that have added the same person.

```
select m.* from members m
join addclique a on m.id = a.adder_id
where a.clique_id = :id

union 

select m.* from members m
join addclique a on m.id = a.clique_id
where a.adder_id = :id
```

Comment: How do i relate these statements to $sql since you have 2 select statements? Do I say:  $sql= "select ***** union select****";?

Comment: Yes its a single query

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to join on `m.id = a.adder_id or m.id = a.clique_id`.  You can do this with `in`:

```
set @id := 4;

select *
from members m
    join addclique a on m.id in (a.adder_id, a.clique_id)
where @id in (a.adder_id, a.clique_id)
  and m.id != @id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e72091/5)

Comment: Why are we setting @id :=4 ?

Comment: @uchejava -- that's just an example for the fiddle to work.  You can remove that line and change it to `:id`.